# Returning a function vs returning a closure

Tags: function, swift, closures

In Swift, as I understand it, closures preserve their environment, while normal functions do not.

Consider `f` (returning a function) and `h` (returning a closure) below.  Both `f()()` and `h()()` return `3`.  Why doesn't `f()()` cause a runtime error?

```
func f() -> () -> Int { 
    let a = 3
    func g() -> Int { 
        return a
    } 
    return g 
} 

func h() -> () -> Int {
    let a = 3
    return { () in a }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you wrote is not exactly true, because according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

> Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any values.
>
> Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function.
>
> Closure expressions are unnamed closures written in a lightweight syntax that can capture values from their surrounding context.

So g() do capture values.

Comment: Thanks Dániel and @Antonio.  I wonder whether for consistency it would have been possible for the designers to avoid introducing the second syntax (`in`).

Comment: Actually you can return it with just { a }, if that was what you meant.

Comment: Not quite, but that's useful too!

Answer (score 1):

An inline function like `g` does preserve the context. Actually functions are named closures, or closures are unnamed functions (whichever definition you prefer).

As stated in the documentation:

> Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures